# My server won't send emails

Tags: php, email, postfix, smtp

I've been sent here by the people at stackoverflow

OK so I know I'm using the right code becuase I have it working on another server but when I try to send an email from a webpage on this particular server using php I get a success message back but the email never gets through.

In /var/log/maillog I see

> Sep 11 14:20:28 ela1 postfix/smtp[11496]: CEE83E151FD: to=[My email address here], relay=none, delay=40, delays=0.08/0.01/40/0, dsn=4.4.3, status=deferred (Host or domain name not found. Name service error for name=btopenworld.co.uk type=MX: Host not found, try again)

Can anyone help?

Comment: Contact your recipient by some other means and get the _correct_ email address from them.

Answer (score 4):

`btopenworld.co.uk` has no [MX records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MX_record), as the log says. Contact the recipient person and ask them for the correct e-mail address or to repair their domain's DNS records.

Comment: As this address is part of BT's network, I believe they have it set without MX records for a reason, it is not a private individual's domain but an ISP domain, so I don't think there's any DNS config to fix.

Comment: Just for the sake of being pedantic: note that in practice you don't need `MX` records to receive mail; generally MTAs will attempt to deliver to the address that the `A` record points to, if there's no `MX` record (but you should _always_ use `MX` records anyway).

Answer (score 2):

From what I see using nslookup:

```
> btopenworld.co.uk
Server:         87.248.160.5
Address:        87.248.160.5#53

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:   btopenworld.co.uk
Address: 213.121.143.193
> set type=MX
> btopenworld.co.uk
Server:         87.248.160.5
Address:        87.248.160.5#53

Non-authoritative answer:
*** Can't find btopenworld.co.uk: No answer

Authoritative answers can be found from:
btopenworld.co.uk
        origin = ns0.bt.net
        mail addr = hostmaster.bt.net
        serial = 2002020923
        refresh = 28800
        retry = 7200
        expire = 604800
        minimum = 86400
>
```

This domain doesn't have any MX records, thus your MTA doesn't know where to send the emails to. The issue is thus from the btopenworld.co.uk domain part and in order to fix this the owner of btopenworld.co.uk needs to be contacted so he adds MX records for the btopenworld.co.uk zone.

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe btopenworld.**co.uk** was ever a valid email destination, only btopenworld.**com** and **btinternet.com**

You could try re-sending your email to address@btopenworld.com as a test and see if that gets through, although according to your example you're using your own email address to test so I would have thought you'd have noticed this problem long before now :-/

Answer (score -3):

Show output of /etc/resolv.conf.This file shows the DNS servers in it.If there is no DNS server in it then you have to add one.Also problem can be with MX ecords in DNS.MX tells the MDA(mail delivery agent) where to route email.So you have to check your DNS configuration also.

Comment: The DNS setup is correct. The given domain does not have a MX record.